# Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()

Tags: php, openssl

I am getting this exception when trying to run my PHP unit tests:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()

What does it mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your version of PHP wasn't compiled with the `openssl` module. If you are building from source, add the module like so:

```
cd /path/to/php-5.4/
./configure --with-openssl
```

Answer (score 25):

I had the same issue. I solved it by editing my **php.ini** file - changing `;extension=php_openssl.dll` to `extension=php_openssl.dll` .

(For my installation, my **php.ini** file was located in my `P:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\conf_files\` directory.)

Answer (score 4):

It means you do not have the [openssl extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) enabled in your PHP install. It needs to be enabled for you to use openssl_* functions.

Answer (score 4):

It means you possibly don't have [openssl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) enabled.

If you are on windows its even easier to load it. Enable it from wamp icon on system tray.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check your configuration **php.ini**:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
;extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "ext"
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

Your php installation either does not have openssl enabled, or you could be running a version of php < 5.3.

To enable openssl, you must re-compile and install php with the "–with-openssl" flag. See [php installation documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/install.php)

Answer (score 0):

For me this error occurred because i had not configured openssl correctly for my PHP.
This is the exact step i followed to rectify this error.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36070260/1221096