# Fatal error php

Tags: php, openssl

i am trying to make a secure log in and registration page using php. i found a code on internet that helped me alot but while debugging and clicking on the button register, an error appeared saying "Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() " when i went to the specified line in the code i found this : "`$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));`" i think i have the 5.3.8 version of php i downloaded the php 5.5.9 thread but it think i didn't install it well. I am on windows. Can alone help me please? I am still a beginner in these stuffs Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212808/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-openssl-random-pseudo-bytes

Comment: @Nouphal.M i saw it but i didnt understand what should i do, i need a clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the `open_ssl` extension on your PHP.ini

Open your PHP.ini , search for this line

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Remove the `;` before the line , save the file and restart your webserver and you are good to go.

### How to find the right php.ini ?

Create a simple test file like `test.php`, add `<?php phpinfo();` and execute it. Search for `Loaded Configuration File` line and see the path next to that line.

Comment: Instead of using `phpinfo()` only to find what is the loaded php.ini file path, I would consider using `php_ini_loaded_file()` function (as of PHP 5.2.4)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran i didnt found php.in in the path , i found two : php.ini-Development and -production i entered them and edit it and got the same error

Comment: Did you follow the instructions I gave in the post ?

Comment: yes i changed both file : php-ini-development and production and the same error

Answer (score 0):

In order to use OpenSSL function you need to install the OpenSSL extension for php.
[Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php)

Comment: i think i have it man , in phpinfo() i found OPENSSL_CONF C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf