# PHP OpenSSL extension not working while installing TYPO3 6.2.2 on Windows 7

Tags: php, windows, apache, typo3, php-openssl

I've installed TYPO3 6.2.2 on Windows 7 but I got an error message as below:

`PHP OpenSSL extension not working Something went wrong while trying to create a new private key for testing. Please check the integration of the PHP OpenSSL extension and if it is installed correctly.`

I try to find the solution on the internet about this error but I cannnot solve this bug.

Can anyone help me to find the solution please? Thanks.

Comment: have you enabled extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini

Comment: I already enabled it.

Comment: and /i guess you restarted Apache after enabling the extension

Answer (score 34):

Solution that worked for me on XAMPP and Windows Vista:

- ***Activate the PHP module openssl***

  Open php.ini and uncomment(delete ';') in:

  `;extension=php_openssl.dll`

  Double-check that the extension is enabled by running phpinfo().
- ***Add a system environment variable "OPENSSL_CONF"*** with value

  `C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf`

  ...assuming you installed xampp into C:\xampp.
- ***Set path to 'openssl.exe'***, which is in C:\xampp\apache\bin

  - Either set `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['binSetup']` in 
    `...\htdocs\typo3_src-6.2.x\typo3\sysext\core\Configuration\DefaultConfiguration.php` to `'openssl=c:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.exe'`
  - or append `c:\xampp\apache\bin` to the environment variable PATH (will work for every PHP script not only TYPO3)
- ***Restart xampp***

Links/sources:

- http://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1318283565
- http://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/116156/

Comment: I have the same problem and even this solution did not help me.

Comment: Make sure to restart the whole xampp control panel (as stated in the answer). Restarting only apache from the xampp control panel is not enough, probably because apache doesn't see the new environment variable(s) this way.

Comment: "Add an environment variable "OPENSSL_CONF" with value" - this should be a system environment variable not the one set with Apache's `SetEnv` instruction. Spent quite some time before realized that.

Comment: @AntonBoritskiy true, thanks for pointing this out. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I am using version `8.1.2` of typo3 and there is no `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['binSetup']` in `DefaultConfiguration.php`

Comment: This worked. It seems to be irrelevant if PHP is on the PATH or if in the PHP.ini `extension=openssl` is commented out and if `openssl.cafile` and `curl.cainfo` points to an existing CRT or PEM file... i dont understand this at all, but im happy that the Typo3 installer (tested with v9) is happy now :-/

Comment: this solution worked for typo3_7.19 with WAMP server that I am using! Just change the path names accordingly for openssl.exe and for openssl.conf

Answer (score 11):

To enable OpenSSL on PHP under Windows, three steps must be taken:

1. enable the extension – make sure to uncomment this line in php.ini:

   `extension=php_openssl.dll`
2. Add the PHP folder to the PATH environment variable of Windows:

   Control Panel –> System –> Advanced System Settings –> Environment Variables.
   Locate the Path variable in the System Variables block.
   Prepend `c:\php;` in front of it, or whatever your PHP path is.
3. Create an additional OPENSSL_CONF environment variable for Windows which contains the full path of the OpenSSL config file of PHP:

   Control Panel –> System –> Advanced System Settings –> Environment Variables.
   In the System Variables block click New...
   Variable name: `OPENSSL_CONF`
   Variable value: `C:\php\extras\ssl\openssl.cnf`
   Modify that value to match your PHP installation directory!

Restart Windows so the environment changes can take effect.

Details on PHP OpenSSL support under Windows can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php).

Answer (score 3):

On typo3 6.2.7on win7 XAMPP 1.8.3

The openSSL error's solution was to create **C:\openssl-1.0.1i-win32\ssl** folder and put **E:\Portables\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf** into it. I got a direction about it from a german website.

How I found it out (just in case versions change), in the shell on XAMPP control panel, openssl command gives

> WARNING: can't open config file: E:/Portables/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf.

But adding the file there does not help. I added and removed the file.

Add `;E:\Portables\xampp\apache\bin` to PATH environment variable (System properties -> Advanced). Run command openssl on a CMD window(not XMPP shell), the message:

> WARNING: can't open config file: c:/openssl-1.0.1i-win32/ssl/openssl.cnf

Add the file there, the addition to environment variable PATH can be removed now.

Adding `OPENSSL_CONF` also did not work for me.

Comment: this worked for me with xampp 7.1.7 and typo3 8.7.3, too

Answer (score 1):

Set a global environment variable OPENSSL_CONF to %ProgramFiles(x86)%\PHP\Current\extras\openssl.cnf

Answer (score 0):

The following solution might only work by manual start of the Apache-Server by click on `apache_start.bat` inside Xampp, other use-cases and server-packages are not tested or covered.

---

**Dealing with several versions of xampp and perhaps additional several frameworks** I searched for an approach that is best fitting to the following requirements:

- A framework never has to know about the configuration or the path to the executable openssl-file (in windows: `openssl.exe`).
- It doesn't matter which server is started, the right path to openssl is always found, fitting to the version of the server. This avoids problems that openssl might be compiled with another version than PHP or Apache-Server.
- Variables never have to be added unflexible and static to the PATH-Variable.
  Instead they shall only be added as long as a server is running.
- Stopping one server-version and starting another server-version is switching without further actions to the right path of `openssl.exe` and `openssl.cnf`.

Based on these developer-requirements the steps I describe are a bit different than the running answers on this page:

1. Enable openssl in the `php.ini`-file of each server-version (i.e. xampp-1, xampp-2, etc.) by removing the leading semicolon of the following line:

   `;extension=php_openssl.dll`
2. Open the file `apache_start.bat` of each server-version and replace the line

   `apache\bin\httpd.exe`

   by the following snippet:

   `SET OPENSSL_CONF=C:\xampp-x\apache\conf\openssl.cnf
   IF EXIST C:\xampp-x\apache\bin SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\xampp-x\apache\bin
   apache\bin\httpd.exe`

   **Pay attention that you everywhere replace `C:\xampp-x\` by the real path to the corresponding server.**
3. Restart xampp either by apache_start.bat or by the xampp-control-panel.

This solution naturally works also with only one server and with the advantage having limited PATH-Variables system-wide defined.

**UPDATE**
If you have still problems related to TYPO3, no matter about the method you chosed, check the cookie_domain in the installtool. It should apply to the current domain or being empty.
A **wrong cookie-domain** can happen if you copy a project from another server, i.e. for development.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the path like below `"config" => "D:/xampp/php/extras/openssl/openssl.cnf",` solved the issue.

```
$key = openssl_pkey_new([
    "config" => "D:/xampp/php/extras/openssl/openssl.cnf",
    'digest_alg' => 'aes256',
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    'encrypt_key' => false,
    'encrypt_key_cipher' => OPENSSL_CIPHER_AES_256_CBC,
]);
openssl_pkey_export_to_file($key, $this->folder . '/private.pem');
```