# TYPO3 wont allow login

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I just installed lamp, with SSL, installed TYPO3 CMS on it, all went well. till it redirects me to login, I entered my correct login credentials, without luck login. I get the following error message.

Your login attempt did not succeed
Make sure to spell your username and password correctly, including upper/lowercase characters.

```
#1 installed lamp
#2 SLL using nginx Let's Encrypt tool
#3 TYPO3 8 LTS , PHP7
```

So I have tried to reinstall multiple times, all goes well, but login. how do I login? What is wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: Which TYPO3 / PHP version are we looking at?

Comment: TYPO3 8 LTS , php7.

Comment: Can you check your typo3conf/PackageStates.php for the 'sv' key?

Comment: @Pascale , Yes the file contains this line inside an array i guise, 'sv' => [
            'packagePath' => 'typo3/sysext/sv/', but no line with svKey/sv_key/key exist there.

Comment: Try setting ['BE'][ 'loginSecurityLevel'] => 'normal' in your typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php

Comment: @Pascale that allowed me login, now i wish to know what's going on? you can explain on an answer, so i chose it.

Answer (score 2):

In case of an errornous OpenSSL Installation or Configuration, the default 'rsa' login provider for TYPO3 8 LTS does not work.

Setting `['BE']['loginSecurityLevel'] => 'normal'` in your typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php is a temporary fix, but you should be looking into your OpenSSL Configuration, e.g.

- Is the OpenSSL PHP Extension installed?
- Is the OpenSSL Binary in the system path?

Comment: Yes, php-openssl is installed, what should i do to make it permanently fixed?

Comment: There are some solutions on StackOverflow, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754996/php-openssl-extension-not-working-while-install-typo3-6-2-2-on-window7

Comment: openssl did not resolve the issue, openssl extension is installed and active, php -m | grep openssl
plus, while installing TYPO3 it did check for php-extensions. i.e. i missed php7-gd it complained about it when i installed it the complain disappeared. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/In-depth/SystemRequirements/Index.html#php-required-extensions , what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of brack down, security level to the normal is no solution. TYPO3 RSA security required SSL enabled in your server. [Here is](https://gist.github.com/GhanshyamBhava/41d3a34acc11cec2a4828b0d4b2c840f) the complete Apache configuration for the windows based system.

Greetings!