# How to enable openSSL in PHP 7.4 with Apache Server 2.4?

Tags: php, apache, openssl

I am aware very similar questions have been around but none seem to have the solution for my problem. I wonder if you could give me a hand with this one. I'll try to be as specific as possible:

- I'm on a Windows x64
- PHP version 7.4.6
- Apache server 2.4.43
- On the php.ini file I uncommented extension=openssl and extension_dir = "ext"
- On the httpd.conf file I added this extra snippet

```
<IfModule php7_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
  PHPIniDir "C:/php-7.4.6"
  LoadFile "C:/php-7.4.6/libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll"
  LoadFile "C:/php-7.4.6/libssl-1_1-x64.dll"
  LoadFile "C:/php-7.4.6/libssh2.dll"
  LoadFile "C:/php-7.4.6/nghttp2.dll"
  LoadFile "C:/php-7.4.6/php7ts.dll"
</IfModule>
```

(I include the LoadFiles as I saw somewhere that that might be solution, well it's not for me at least)

- Checked on the command line the modules installed (php -m) and it seems that the ssl module is enabled. However when checking with the  extension_loaded  ('openssl') instruction it returns a false. Also, with phpinfo() I see that OpenSSL support is disabled and I should install (ext/openssl).
  I don't know why they are telling me opposite things. https wrapper is not enabled either.
- I checked if both php and apache were reading from different php.ini files and they both say the same thing:
  Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\WINDOWS
  Loaded Configuration File   C:\php-7.4.6\php.ini

Which btw I understand little, as there is no php.ini in the Windows folder. I understand that the file is got from the path specified below.

- In the ext folder there is the php_openssl.dll file.
- I tried to include C:\php-7.4.6\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll as environmental variable as I saw that in a different link.
- And yes, I restarted the server several times.
  I reckon I ran out of options and I don't know what else I should do. Thanks for your help!
  I try to attach the links that I've been visiting, although I'm sure I'm leaving some behind as I lost track.

[Unable to find the wrapper "https" with file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643572/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-with-file-get-contents/43513546)

[OpenSSL Support disabled in Apache 2.4/PHP 7.4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045695/openssl-support-disabled-in-apache-2-4-php-7-4-4)

[PHP OpenSSL extension not working while install Typo3 6.2.2 on window7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754996/php-openssl-extension-not-working-while-install-typo3-6-2-2-on-window7)

[How to enable HTTPS stream wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305954/how-to-enable-https-stream-wrappers)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately I managed to get it to work and I want to share with you all the solution in case you are facing the same problem.
I happened to think about checking the error logs of Apache and the following error was registered for every module: Unable to load dynamic library. It was trying to take the module from the /ext folder, which it didn't know where it was, so what I did was to change in the php.ini file the extension_dir to an absolute PATH "C:\php-7.4.6\ext" and now it works like a dream!

Comment: Great, that did the trick. Although I used forward slashes in stead of back slash.

Answer (score 2):

There is a line in php.ini:

```
;extension_dir = "ext"
```

You just have to uncomment it in addition to uncomment `extension=php_openssl.dll` as well.