# How to install and enable PHP 5.5 extensions

Tags: php, installation

I am setting up Flarum forum software, I would like to install mbstring, pdo_mysql, openssl, json, gd, dom, fileinfo at once, as the instructions say, I need these.

Comment: Any reason why you need to edit my question? any real reason?

Comment: You want to install these php modules where? Which OS?

Comment: Sorry. Ubuntu. it just says I need these php modules installed.

Comment: Do you want to install these on a webspace or do you have a (v)server? If you have a webspace you need to contact your hoster. If you have a (v)server you can install these via SSH and `apt-get install`. Use `apt-cache search php` to look which modules can be installed with `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1):

These are called modules / extensions and can be enabled in the php.ini

Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212808/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-openssl-random-pseudo-bytes)

Comment: Due to the weird editing, this was a totally unhelpful answer, I want to install a group of php Addons or modules, not fatal errors of any thing.

Comment: Unhelpfull? calling `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` without enabling enabling the `openssl` extension in the php.ini leads to a `Fatal error: Call to undefined function` error. Using any guide installing a php server on Ubuntu you automatically have these extensions pre-installed but only have to enable them. If not, they are in the `apache2` package or search for them  in the terminal using `apt-get install php5-{press tab here}`.