# OpenSSL installed but not working

Tags: php, apache, openssl

I'm trying to use the CryptoJS AES module in my php project but I have the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()
>   [image]

Checking the configuration of PHP I noticed that both OpenSSL and Mcrypt are enabled

[image]

Anyone know more about this error? could be some restrinction to my user? (I'm on a shared-hosting). The PHP version is 5.2.1.7 on Apache2. 
Thanks

I've also checked if PHP has been compiled with the correct --openssl and so it is

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl\_random\_pseudo\_bytes()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212808/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-openssl-random-pseudo-bytes)

Comment: You should move away from a host who thinks that running PHP 5.2 is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade PHP to version >= 5.3.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I may check with my host if is possible to upgrade to PHP 5.3.