# Installing open Cart using XAMPP

Tags: php, opencart

I'm getting this error when I try installing open Cart on my system.

Fatal error:

> Call to undefined function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes_() in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\system\library\session.php on line 33

Comment: Make sure that `php_openssl.dll` is activated in your `php.ini`

Comment: Ive done that, but I'm still having the same error

Comment: Are you sure you enabled it for the right PHP version?

Comment: I think that's dy issue....Lemme try fixing it thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl\_random\_pseudo\_bytes()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212808/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-openssl-random-pseudo-bytes)

Comment: Don't use XAMP after all, I hardly recommend a "plain" Webserver like Apache2. On Windows, you can use a virtual machine running Linux for the server. Or use a Webserver running on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

First of uncomment curl library in php.ini

Comment: Okk... Thanks...I've installed it now

Answer (score 0):

Edit **php.ini** file - changing `;extension=php_openssl.dll` to `extension=php_openssl.dll` .

OR

Your php installation either does not have openssl enabled, or you could be running a version of php < 5.3.

To enable openssl, you must re-compile and install php with the "–with-openssl" flag. See [php installation documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/install.php)

OR

Your version of PHP wasn't compiled with the `openssl` module. If you are building from source, add the module like so:

```
cd /path/to/php-5.4/
./configure --with-openssl
```